# Need help running a nested program call from Windows 10 .BAT file without "UNC paths are not supported" error

Tags: windows, batch-file

So here's my situation. I currently have the following directory structure on both: local hard drive `D:` and on mapped network drive `Z:`.

```
D:\Audio\mp3\
             Artist 1 - Album 1
             Artist 1 - Album 2
             Artist 1 - Album 3
             Artist 2 - Album 1
             etc.
```

Likewise, I have my network share `\\Diskstation\music` mapped to `Z:`, hence:

```
Z:\mp3\
       Artist 1 - Album 1
       Artist 1 - Album 2
       Artist 1 - Album 3
       Artist 2 - Album 1
       etc.
```

I am currently using two command line applications running from within my .BAT file to perform audio gain changes on all my mp3 files in these folders and subfolders.

The first program I use is called `sweep.exe`. It basically allows me to "sweep" all of the files that meet my file search type, *.mp3, into another program and go recursively through every folder doing so.

The program being called to actually make the gain changes is `mp3gain`. My .BAT file that runs on the local `D:` drive looks like the following:

```
d:
del gainadjust_output.txt
cd Audio
cd mp3
sweep mp3gain /a /c /d 7 /q /f *.mp3 > d:\gainadjust_output.txt
```

When double clicking the .BAT file that is running locally from drive `D:`, I get output like the following:

```
Entering directory: '220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight'
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 01 - Walking In Starlight.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 02 - System Overload.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 03 - Broken Promises.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 04 - Alive.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 05 - Blind.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 06 - Stranded.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 07 - Get Me Out.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 08 - The Waiting.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 09 - Through The Wastelands.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 10 - Burning Heart.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 11 - Take A Good Look.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 12 - One Good Reason.mp3
220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 13 - Guiding Light.mp3

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 01 - Walking In Starlight.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 02 - System Overload.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 03 - Broken Promises.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 04 - Alive.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 05 - Blind.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 06 - Stranded.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 07 - Get Me Out.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 08 - The Waiting.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 09 - Through The Wastelands.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 10 - Burning Heart.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 11 - Take A Good Look.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 12 - One Good Reason.mp3 are necessary

No changes to 220 Volt - (2014) Walking In Starlight - 13 - Guiding Light.mp3 are necessary

Entering directory: '24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz'
24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz - 01 - Tick, Tick ,tick.mp3
24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz - 02 - Stuntman.mp3
24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz - 03 - My Desire.mp3
24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz - 04 - Peace & Love.mp3
24 - 7 Spyz - (1991) This Is 24 - 7 Spyz - 05 - Earthquake.mp3
```

So everything is running like a champ.

However, when I run the near same BAT file from the mapped drive `Z:` which looks like this:

```
z:
del gainadjust_output.txt
cd mp3
sweep mp3gain /a /c /d 7 /q /f *.mp3 > z:\gainadjust_output.txt
```

The operation fails due to what appears to be the UNC issue I mentioned in the subject:

```
'\\Diskstation\music\mp3'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
*.mp3
Can't open *.mp3 for reading

Entering directory: 'Constantine - (2013) Resign Due'
'\\Diskstation\music\mp3\Constantine - (2013) Resign Due'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
*.mp3
Can't open *.mp3 for reading
```

I've tried using `pushd ~dp0` and `popd` to stick the current drive letter on the stack and use that as an alias in the BAT file, but that still seems to just use the UNC path `\\Diskstation\music` which causes the UNC error again.

I'm not certain if this issue is the use of the `sweep.exe` program causing `Z:` not to be used, or if this is strictly an issue with running the BAT file on a network drive.

If you feel there is a way to do the same thing `sweep.exe` is doing passing files to the `mp3gain.exe` which also gets around the UNC issue, I'd love to hear about it.  Right now, I've torn out quite a bit of hair and gone cross-eyed from googling UNC path issues with BAT files, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your first example script should replace the first four lines with `CD /D D:\Audio\mp3`, _(or `CD /D "D:\Audio\mp3"` for good practice)_, and your second example script should replace the first three lines with `CD /D Z:\mp3`, _(or `CD /D "Z:\mp3"` for good practice)_. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `cd /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to read its usage information. _For the same level of robustness I'd also advise changing to this syntax too: `"D:\gainadjust_output.txt"`, and `"Z:\gainadjust_output.txt"`_

Comment: Additionally, instead of pre-mapping your network drive, you do not really need to do that, you could just use `PushD \\Diskstation\music\mp3`, which will create a temporary map, and make it your current directory. As soon as you've finished in that location just use the `PopD` command to return to your previous directory location. Please open a Command Prompt window, and `[ENTER]` both `pushd /?` and then `popd /?` to see if there is any usage information to help you.

Comment: @Mofi  Thanks so much for the detailed answer.  It worked like a charm!!!  I have no idea where all of your posts went to answering the question, but they were perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here was the solution which I guess @Mofi felt the need to remove and give me a negative rep for.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if "%~d0" == "\\" (set "OutputFile=%~dp0gainadjust_output.txt") else set "OutputFile=%~d0\gainadjust_output.txt"
(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*.mp3" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do mp3gain.exe /a /c /d 7 /q /f "%%I")>"%OutputFile%"
endlocal
```

Thanks again for the solution, @Mofi, even if you felt the need to alter it, after the fact.